# Epipolar line using essential matrix for calibrated camera is wrong

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I wanted to get the essential or fundamental matrix for calibrated cameras (R, T, Ks are given).

There are two cameras. Is this step correct to get the essential matrix and epipolar line?. The result I have is totally wrong.

```
# P1 - first transformation matrix world to cam1
# P2 - second transformation matrix world to cam2



def skew(x):
    x = x.flatten()
    return np.array([[0, -x[2], x[1]],
                    [x[2], 0, -x[0]],
                    [-x[1], x[0], 0]])

P21 = np.linalg.inv(P2) @ P1



R = P21[:3, :3]
T = P21[:3, 3]

# projection matrices
P1 = np.c_[np.eye(3), np.zeros(3)]
P2 = np.c_[R, T]

#essential matrix
E1 = skew(T) @ P2 @ np.linalg.pinv(P1)

pt1=(x1,y1)

pt1=undistort((x1,y1))

Pt1=[(x1-cx)/fx, (y1-cy)/fy]

Pt1h=[pt1[0], pt[1], 1.0]

Epliline1= E1@pt1h
```

Are those steps above correct if I want to use distortion parameters?

Here I will give the details of the cameras:

Camera1.

```
K1 = array([[1.13423076e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 1.02850079e+03],
       [0.00000000e+00, 8.25907478e+02, 5.63612899e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
dist1 = array([[-0.3921685 ,  0.18873927, -0.00285428, -0.00478303, -0.0478105 ]])
R1: array([[ 0.87748302,  0.47592599, -0.05931269],
       [-0.306075  ,  0.65090299,  0.69472541],
       [ 0.36924469, -0.59145562,  0.71682537]])
T1: array([[-1.86579737],
           [ 0.43997991],
           [ 2.80324197]])
```

Camera2.

```
K2: array([[1.13968506e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 9.85549834e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 8.26601887e+02, 5.86985726e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]]), 
dist2: array([[-3.80880220e-01,  1.83123508e-01, -5.59300663e-04,
         1.97688021e-04, -5.11559635e-02]])
R2 : array([[-0.99235374,  0.12149541, -0.0217467 ],
       [-0.10731501, -0.76228259,  0.63828578],
       [ 0.06097166,  0.63573903,  0.76949226]]), 
T2 : array([[0.5810168 ],
       [1.86135225],
       [1.6348977 ]])
```

Comment: For some who are struggling to find this, you have to get the fundamental matrix by multiplying: inv(k1).T @ Essential_matrix @ inv(k) to get the fundamental matrix. Then use the same size of the image for all. intrinsic calibration, extrinsic calibration and to get the epipolar line.

Comment: You may share your results to compare with mine below. Note that they should be equal up to a scale factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `skew` function is simply the cross product matrix.
Like OpenCV does, I initially move the world origin in the first camera (so I only have `R` and `T` relative to the second camera), and then I use the following code to calculate the fundamental matrix F:

```
# Alternative formula by
# Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision, by Richard Hartley and Andrew Zisserman
vv = skew( K1.dot(R.T).dot(T) )
F = (np.linalg.inv(K2).T).dot(self.R).dot(K1.T).dot(vv)
```

Then the essential matrix is obtainable like:

```
E = K2.T.dot(F).dot(K1)
```

The results are:

```
F [[ 1.13278823e-01 -1.35253176e+00 -4.88980254e+02]
 [-1.06844252e+00  4.04566728e-01  1.88300039e+02]
 [-5.54697063e+02  1.71231655e+03  6.35764837e+05]]

E [[  146431.66676676 -1273103.54255988 -1293288.66957507]
 [-1001726.06809778   276196.36212759  -564217.70767202]
 [-1213871.5038731    509423.0312259   -488699.08411468]]
```

I got sick of writing such boilerplate, so I came up with a [simple library](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo) to manage stereo rigs. The full code I used is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import simplestereo as ss

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    res1 = (1280,720) # Camera resolution is required by initialisation 
    res2 = (1280,720) # but should not change F end E results.
    
    # Raw camera 1 parameters (an NumPy arrays)
    K1 = np.array([[1.13423076e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 1.02850079e+03],
           [0.00000000e+00, 8.25907478e+02, 5.63612899e+02],
           [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
           
    dist1 = np.array([[-0.3921685 ,  0.18873927, -0.00285428, -0.00478303, -0.0478105 ]])
    
    R1 = np.array([[ 0.87748302,  0.47592599, -0.05931269],
           [-0.306075  ,  0.65090299,  0.69472541],
           [ 0.36924469, -0.59145562,  0.71682537]])
    
    T1 = np.array([[-1.86579737],
               [ 0.43997991],
               [ 2.80324197]])
    
    # Camera 2           
    K2 = np.array([[1.13968506e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 9.85549834e+02],
           [0.00000000e+00, 8.26601887e+02, 5.86985726e+02],
           [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
            
    dist2 = np.array([[-3.80880220e-01,  1.83123508e-01, -5.59300663e-04,
             1.97688021e-04, -5.11559635e-02]])
    
    R2 = np.array([[-0.99235374,  0.12149541, -0.0217467 ],
           [-0.10731501, -0.76228259,  0.63828578],
           [ 0.06097166,  0.63573903,  0.76949226]])
            
    T2 = np.array([[0.5810168 ],
           [1.86135225],
           [1.6348977 ]])

    
    # As a convention, the world origin must be in the left camera.
    # Move the world origin into the first camera (IMPORTANT)
    R, T = ss.utils.moveExtrinsicOriginToFirstCamera(R1, R2, T1, T2)
    
    # Create the StereoRig
    rig = ss.StereoRig(res1, res2, K1, K2, dist1, dist2, R, T) 

    print("F", rig.getFundamentalMatrix())
    print("E", rig.getEssentialMatrix())
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I will accept your answer. But, can you please tell me how to use distortion which was part of the question? 
You directly used intrinsics, rotation, and translation but did not apply the distortion.

Comment: Hi. Epipolar geometry works after distortion is corrected. You first correct distortion, then your image is on a perfect plane and you can work with epipolar geometry only.
To correct distortion you need `cv2.undistort`  or you can refer to this example in the same library https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo/blob/master/examples/004a%20UndistortImages.py

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Is it possible to use undistorted points for that?
We used that but it doesn't seem to work.  We undistorted the points and then used that to get the epiline. After that, we used epiline to get the point and distorted that point again. However, the result is something very big value.

Comment: When we used distorted points it is working but there is some error (~5 - 20 px ) and that error gets higher on the edges of the image.